# connecting elements with similar nodes in python

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx

I'm thinking there is a python networkx solution to the following problem, but I haven't figured it out. Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[100,100,200,200,300,300,400,400,500,500,600,600], 'Node':[4,5,6,4,5,8,5,7,1,5,2,3], 'Stress':[12,14,11,10,9,7,12,13,5,6,14,11]})
```

which looks like

| ID | Node | Stress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 4 | 12 |
| 100 | 5 | 14 |
| 200 | 6 | 11 |
| 200 | 4 | 10 |
| 300 | 5 | 9 |
| 300 | 8 | 7 |
| 400 | 5 | 12 |
| 400 | 7 | 13 |
| 500 | 1 | 5 |
| 500 | 5 | 6 |
| 600 | 2 | 14 |
| 600 | 3 | 11 |

Now what I need to do is, construct a function f(ID, lower_Stress, upper_Stress), that takes a given ID and lower and upper bounds for Stress (inclusive), and outputs all the IDs which have connecting nodes with stress levels within the given limits of lower_Stress and upper_Stress.

For example, f(100, 7,13) would output IDs: 100, 200, 300, 400. Note that ID == 500 would not be included because, although it has a connecting node with 100 (i.e. Node == 5), its stress levels are outside the boundary. ID == 600 would also not be included because its nodes do not connect with ID==100.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds for me like you have a bipartite graph (IDs and node) and could create the projection on (IDs) while having for the edges the min and max stress level the connected node(s). Then your function would only need to retrieve the first neighbourhood of the given ID and filter according to min/max in the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm going to throw out an answer (to my own question). This does the trick, but could probably be made cleaner/faster:

```
import networkx as nx

def get_neighbors(ID, lower, upper):
  df_test = df_test[(df_test['Stress'] <= upper) & (df_test['Stress'] >= lower)]

  gs = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_test,'ID','Node')
  connected_components = nx.connected_components(gs)
  d = {y:i for i, x in enumerate(connected_components) for y in x}

  df_test['group'] = df_test.ID.replace(d)

  id_group = df_test[df_test['ID'] == ID]['group']
  id_neighbors = df_test[df_test['group'] == id_group.iloc[0]]
  
  return id_neighbors
```